# Is it possible to create a StreamedContent List?

Tags: java, primefaces

I need to create a list of .pdf files and wrapp it all in one zip file using  org.primefaces.model.StreamedContent. Is it possible??? This is my general idea:

```
    private StreamedContent fileDownload;
    private ArrayList<StreamedContent> filesDownload;
     for (Cobranca boleto : cob) {
        this.boletoPDF = null;
        TndFabricaBoletoWrapper wrapper = new TndFabricaBoletoWrapper();
    
        wrapper = this.cobrancaBusiness.processarBoleto(boleto, wrapper);
        wrapper.setDownload(true);
    
        JBoleto jBoleto = TndFabricaJBoleto.getJBoleto(wrapper);
        jBoleto.addBoleto();
    
        this.boletoPDF = jBoleto.closeBoleto();
    
        File anexo = File.createTempFile("Boleto", ".pdf");
        Arquivo.salvarArquivo(anexo, this.boletoPDF);
    
        byte[] arq = Arquivo.zipByte(anexo, 9);
    
        this.fileDownload = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(arq), "application/zip", "Boleto");
        this.filesDownload.add(this.fileDownload);
}
((DefaultStreamedContent) this.filesDownload).setName("Boleto" + ".zip"); //this is where the download action usually happens... But the (DefaultStreamdContent) cannot be cast to an ArrayList...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is get a byte-array of every PDF-Content, add this to a zip-File and then produce a StreamedContent of this Zip-File.
Supposing you have a List<byte[]> with all your PDF-Contents, it could be something like this:

```
public StreamedContent getZipDownload(List<byte[]> contentList){
    StreamedContent result = null;
    
    try {

        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ZipOutputStream zipOut = new ZipOutputStream(baos);
        for (int i = 0; i < contentList.size(); i++) {
            String name = "" + i + ".pdf";

            zipOut.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(name));
            zipOut.write(contentList.get(i));
            zipOut.closeEntry();

        }

        zipOut.finish();
        zipOut.close();
        result = DefaultStreamedContent.builder()
                    .name("pdfFiles.zip")
                    .contentType("application/octet-stream")
                    .stream(() -> new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())).build();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Download failed, error in Zip Creation", e);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Man, thanks for the help. But because of legacy issues I'm using Primefaces 3.5, so this .builder() is not avaliable. I'm tryng to ajust it but its not quite working...At your response? `new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray())).build()`, is the "baos" variable correct? I mean, you didn't pass any value to it...

Comment: And here's the final part of my code where i'm having some issues 
`this.fileDownload = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()), "application/octet-stream", "Boleto");
  ((DefaultStreamedContent) this.fileDownload).setName("Boleto" + ".zip");`

Comment: The ZipOutputstream is created from the ByteArrayOutputstream, so we are writing to it through the ZipoutputStream and baos.toByteArray() returns a byte[] with the conten of the Zip-File. I think you don't need the setName, you can use ```DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(baos.toByteArray()), "application/octet-stream", "Boleto.zip");``` I'm not sure if this solves your issues, i never worked with primefaces 3.5

Comment: I see... Unfortunately It's not working for me... The zip is sent to be dowloaded but the pdfs inside are all broken...